# Owl Carousel Not Showing On Bootstrap 5

Tags: html, css, owl-carousel, bootstrap-5

i try to use Owl Carousel version 2.3.4 with cdn, but it is not working, here is my code, the carousel didn't show up, Thankyou

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.carousel.min.css" integrity="sha512-tS3S5qG0BlhnQROyJXvNjeEM4UpMXHrQfTGmbQ1gKmelCxlSEBUaxhRBj/EFTzpbP4RVSrpEikbmdJobCvhE3g==" crossorigin="anonymous" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.theme.default.min.css" integrity="sha512-sMXtMNL1zRzolHYKEujM2AqCLUR9F2C4/05cdbxjjLSRvMQIciEPCQZo++nk7go3BtSuK9kfa/s+a4f4i5pLkw==" crossorigin="anonymous" />

<div class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
      <div class="item"><h4>1</h4></div>
      <div class="item"><h4>2</h4></div>
      <div class="item"><h4>3</h4></div>
      <div class="item"><h4>4</h4></div>
      <div class="item"><h4>5</h4></div>
      <div class="item"><h4>6</h4></div>
      <div class="item"><h4>7</h4></div>
      <div class="item"><h4>8</h4></div>
      <div class="item"><h4>9</h4></div>
      <div class="item"><h4>10</h4></div>
      <div class="item"><h4>11</h4></div>
      <div class="item"><h4>12</h4></div>
  </div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
```

$(".owl-carousel").owlCarousel();
});

```
    $('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
loop:true,
margin:10,
nav:true,
responsive:{
    0:{
        items:1
    },
    600:{
        items:3
    },
    1000:{
        items:5
    }
}
```

})

```
<!-- Jquery -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-894YE6QWD5I59HgZOGReFYm4dnWc1Qt5NtvYSaNcOP+u1T9qYdvdihz0PPSiiqn/+/3e7Jo4EaG7TubfWGUrMQ==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<!-- Owl Carousel -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/owl.carousel.min.js" integrity="sha512-bPs7Ae6pVvhOSiIcyUClR7/q2OAsRiovw4vAkX+zJbw3ShAeeqezq50RIIcIURq7Oa20rW2n2q+fyXBNcU9lrw==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: If your code is in that order it won't work. You need to import jquery and owl scripts first... Then use it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to import jquery and owl scripts before your custom javascript code.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.carousel.min.css"
    integrity="sha512-tS3S5qG0BlhnQROyJXvNjeEM4UpMXHrQfTGmbQ1gKmelCxlSEBUaxhRBj/EFTzpbP4RVSrpEikbmdJobCvhE3g=="
    crossorigin="anonymous" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.theme.default.min.css"
    integrity="sha512-sMXtMNL1zRzolHYKEujM2AqCLUR9F2C4/05cdbxjjLSRvMQIciEPCQZo++nk7go3BtSuK9kfa/s+a4f4i5pLkw=="
    crossorigin="anonymous" />

<div class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
    <div class="item">
        <h4>1</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <h4>2</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <h4>3</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <h4>4</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <h4>5</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <h4>6</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <h4>7</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <h4>8</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <h4>9</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <h4>10</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <h4>11</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <h4>12</h4>
    </div>
</div>
<!--Jquery -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-894YE6QWD5I59HgZOGReFYm4dnWc1Qt5NtvYSaNcOP+u1T9qYdvdihz0PPSiiqn/+/3e7Jo4EaG7TubfWGUrMQ==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<!-- Owl Carousel -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
<!-- custom JS code after importing jquery and owl -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".owl-carousel").owlCarousel();
    });

    $('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
        loop: true,
        margin: 10,
        nav: true,
        responsive: {
            0: {
                items: 1
            },
            600: {
                items: 3
            },
            1000: {
                items: 5
            }
        }
    })
</script>
```